# Is it better to override methods in classes or make methods general?

Tags: design, database, python, object-oriented-design, inheritance

I am creating the backend of a microservice that will serve as a tool to see in real time how the company's employees are distributed by projects and what days they have assigned to each one. The database I have raised looks like this:

[image]

```
ModelType = TypeVar("ModelType", bound=Base)
CreateSchemaType = TypeVar("CreateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
UpdateSchemaType = TypeVar("UpdateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)


class CRUDBase(Generic[ModelType, CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType]):
    def __init__(self, model: ModelType):
        """CRUD object with default methods to Create, Read, Update,
        Delete (CRUD).
        **Parameters**
        * `model`: A Tortoise ORM model class
        * `schema`: A Pydantic model (schema) class
        """
        self.model = model


    async def get_all(self) -> list[ModelType]:
        db_objs = await self.model.all().values()
        return db_objs
    
    async def get_by_name(self, name_in: str) -> Optional[ModelType]:
        """Returns 'None' when :attr:'CRUDBase.model' does not have attribute
        'name'.
        """
        try:
            db_obj = await self.model.filter(name = name_in).first().values()
        except Exception:
            return None
        
        return db_obj

    async def create(self, obj_in: CreateSchemaType) -> ModelType:
        obj_in_data = jsonable_encoder(obj_in)
        db_obj = self.model(**obj_in_data)
        await db_obj.save()
        return db_obj
```

...I cut the update and delete methods to summarize. This way I can save myself from rewriting a lot of code inheriting from CRUDBase. For example:

```
class CRUDDepartment(CRUDBase[Department, DepartmentCreate, DepartmentUpdate]):
    pass

deparment = CRUDDepartment(Department)
```

The problem is that in some entities there are some differences with respect to the CRUDBase. For example in the case of the Users entity, the attribute is not called "name", its called "username", besides having to apply encryption to the passwords (it would only apply to users). My idea in general is to use the CRUDBase for all entities, then I have the following options. -Make CRUDBase very general (paying the price of complicating it a bit) so that its methods can be used in the entities (for example filter by username and encrypt passwords). -Rewrite methods in each entity depending on the slight variations between entities. Which one should I choose?

Also, I must take into account that in some entities I need to extend CRUDBase to add functionalities that not all of them must have. Would it be well implemented like this?

Update:

```
async def get_by_attribute(
        self,
        field: str, 
        value: Any
        ) -> Optional[ModelType]:
        """Returns 'None' when :attr:'CRUDBase.model' does not have attribute
        'field'.
        """
        try:
            db_obj = await self.model.filter(**{field:value}).first().values()
        except Exception:
            return None
        
        return db_obj
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious to me that `get_by_name()` belongs in `CRUDBase`.

It seems like you want this:

```
class NamedEntity(CRUDBase):

    def get_by_name ...
```

and then relevant entities could inherit from *that*. But not `User`
(or `Users` if your local naming convention insists on
plurals for some reason).

---

Here is my biggest criticism of `CRUDBase`:
It lacks a """docstring""".

The documentation burden for local variables is very small.
It goes up for private (`_helper()`) APIs, and
especially for public APIs.
Any given `class` might be "small" and have
a self-explanatory name.
But for an
[ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html)
that will be extended, we *need* to see a docstring, please.
Why?
So we know what belongs in, and what belongs outside the class.
Which is what the current "get_by_name" controversy is about.
A bit of documentation would *specify* what a class
is [responsible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle)
for, would *nip* any debates in the bud before they start.

Use docstrings to help guide your design, so you know when it's OK
to "add kitchen sink" to a class, and when the class is
telling you "hey, don't add that, find another place for it!"

Comment: Hello, my problem is that in general for each entity I need to do a CRUD. So I thought of creating a CRUDBase so that everyone can inherit and implement these methods, each entity has some additional methods particular to each other (some shared). For example, projects must have a method that allows viewing all the assignments they have (a method that does not need any other entity).

Comment: I have thought of some design pattern that can help me but I'm not sure which one to use, can you help me, or should I just put a CRUDBase, and for each entity extend the class with inheritance by adding the necessary methods?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you use a mixture of overridden methods and non-overridden methods.

Let's say the end effect of a method should be that the implementation in classes X and Y calls your database with slightly different parameters. The call is quite complex. You don't want to duplicate the code.

You could have a trivial private method that for example just returns a field name, so that the the complex method now can have identical code for both classes and doesn't need to be overridden; it just calls the trivial private method.

Or you write a method that is not overridden and gets the call differences as a parameter. Now the two methods that you override are trivial; they call the common code with a simple additional argument.

A third way is that you store the differences in a variable, and you store different values when you initialise instances of different classes. The advantage is that if you have multiple small differences, you can set them up all in the same place per class.

The principle is that you always want methods that you override to be as simple as possible, especially since you don't want to make changes in five overridden methods in the future.

Comment: Hello, it occurred to me to create the CRUDBase interface with the methods to: get all, get by field, update by field and delete by field. What I did was not declare the field to use as such but pass it as a parameter in the methods (please see the code after "update" in the question). Subsequently, for each class corresponding to each entity, I will add the necessary methods. Could you give me your opinion of this implementation? please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've chosen a bad example for your general question. Its generally accepted now that "how to persist to a database" logic should be on a separate class to the object itself.

The obvious reason is "what if you want to save to a different database, or a file or a etc". Although this is often countered with "I'm never going to change my database" once you have tried the repository pattern its hard to go back. Your objects are neater and you don't have the generalising problem of GetByName, GetByDate, GetListWithWhereConditonThatOnlyWorksForThisObject etc you have a 'single responsibility' for objects.

More generally inheritance is still used, but falling out of favour due to the complexity it adds over simple composition.

If you have a hardcoded repository object with SaveDepartment(dept) and GetProjectsByCustomerId(id) you will not be making DRY code, but you will save yourself a lot of thinking time.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Estoy un poco confundido con la implementacion que me comentas. Deberia entonces tener en una clase Repository con todos los posibles metodos para interactuar con la base de datos y despues usar los metodos de esa clase para todos los modelos? No quedaria mal una clase con tantos metodos?  O deberia es crear una clase para cada metodo? Podrias explicarmelo?. Lo que pasa es que para todos los siete modelos necesito hacer un CRUD basico, y para cada modelo algun par de operaciones mas.

Comment: sí, en mi opinión, una sola clase de repositorio funciona mejor. Los muchos métodos pueden hacer una clase larga, pero siempre se puede dividir si es necesario y, de hecho, creo que encontrará que cada clase o clase con niños tendrá sus propias formas únicas de seleccionar de la base de datos, lo que hace una método genérico difícil de implementar.#